# Ambiguity of "sōlus"

Tags: ambiguity

> Dædalus solus volare didicit.

Does that mean:

- Dædalus alone learned to fly?
- Dædalus learned to fly alone?
- Dædalus learned on his own to fly?

How could you indicate each of those meanings without ambiguity?

Comment: Excellent question! All three translations look equally correct to me. Usually relative or other subordinate clauses are a good way around ambiguities, but I don't see how to make them work here.

Comment: I agree that all three are possible translations. For the third meaning, you could disambiguate by saying e.g. *sine magistro*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I was thinking that _sōlus_ was only an adjective, so the meaning is the first choice, since in the second two a verb is being modified. No? I thought of the question because I couldn't think of an adverb for "doing something all by yourself". I'm not sure that _sōlum_ fits, since (I think) it usually carries a meaning like "merely" or "barely".

Comment: I think *solus* can modify the implicit subject of *volare* (though it would be good to see some classical parallels to this construction).

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably translate them, in the order you have them, as

> Dædalus solus volare didicit.
>
> Dædalus volare incomitate didicit.
>
> Dædalus volare nullo magistro didicit.

(Actually for the third I'd probably use *Dædalus se volare docuit*, but that's not really an answer to your question.)

Comment: Actually, I was indeed wondering if _Dædalus se volare docuit_ was the natural way to say this. I wasn't sure if _se docere_ makes sense in Latin the way "teach yourself" does in English. Thanks!

Comment: @BenKovitz I think that's right. There's nothing wrong with Joel's, but *se docere* is just also a natural way of putting it. There aren't too many hits for *se docere* side by side, but there is enough, and more, I'm sure, if you put a few words betwixt.